# Books about theoretical basis in log management

Tags: logging

I'm looking for a books about theoretical basis in log management, not about tools. I need it to write my master's thesis.

I need books about:

- log sources, log collection
- storage techniques, storing logs
- log analysis (maybe statistical analysis, data mining)
- analysis techniques
- reviewing logs for potential problems, methods of reviewing logs
- how to protect logs (remote logging, replication, write to cd)
- what can we do with logs? (automated tasks, alerts)
- maybe you will propose something?

I found:

- "Logging and Log Management: The Authoritative Guide to Understanding the Concepts Surrounding Logging and Log Management" Anton Chuvakin; Kevin Schmidt; Chris Phillips
- "Handbook of Research on Web Log Analysis" Bernard J. Jansen; Amanda Spink; Isak Taksa

but maybe you know others?

Comment: Have you thought about narrowing your focus to just the analysis? Anomaly detection is still a fairly difficult problem in need of more research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start learning about data mining [here](http://www.youtube.com/view%5Fplay%5Flist?p=A89DCFA6ADACE599) and if, you need a book, try [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321321367) one.

For more on Machine learning you could go to
[videolectures.net](http://www.youtube.com/view%5Fplay%5Flist?p=A89DCFA6ADACE599)

A great introductory lecture on the site is [Machine Learning, Probability and Graphical Models](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321321367) by Sam Roweis.

Next, you can have a look at Tom Mitchell's seminar [The Discipline and Future of Machine Learning](http://videolectures.net/Top/Computer_Science/Machine_Learning/). Here is a direct link to the [video [mov]](http://videolectures.net/mlss06tw_roweis_mlpgm/).
And the [Syllabus](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/user/mitchell/ftp/mlbook.html) page has a good list of recommended texts:

- [Neural Networks for Pattern Recognition](http://ocw.mit.edu/OcwWeb/Electrical-Engineering-and-Computer-Science/6-867Fall-2006/Syllabus/index.htm) by Christopher Bishop
- [Pattern Classification](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198538642) by Richard Duda et. al.
- [The Elements of Statistical Learning: Data Mining, Inference and Prediction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471056693) by T.R. Hastie et. al.
- [Information Theory, Inference, and Learning Algorithms](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387952845) by David MacKay
- [Machine Learning](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/mackay/itila/book.html) by Tom Mitchell

Answer (score 0):

Loved [Applied Security Visualization](http://secviz.org/content/applied-security-visualization), even though a bit dated is some respect, it is the foundation of a number of very interesting and innovative concepts that may serve you well during the formulation of some aspects of your thesis. Particularly when turning logs into meaningful information...